# MySQL Error in Python

Tags: python, mysql

> I need to insert a record into the table MemberDetails but I end up with the error stating " _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'I' at line 1") "

```
sql5="INSERT INTO MemberDetails VALUES"+"("+"'2016-2020','"+PhoneNum+"','VEC','"+Address+"','"+StuID+"','"+DOB+"','1000','"+Name+"','"+Pass+"','"+dept+"','"+year+"','"+sec+"')"    
cursor.execute(sql5)
```

Comment: Can you show the value of `sql5` after all the variables are substituted? Probably one of the variables has a quote in it, this is causing the syntax error. You should use a prepared query.

Comment: this is my new sql5: sql5="INSERT INTO MemberDetails ( Validity, PhoneNUM, College, Address, MemberID, DOB, Credits, MEMame, Password, Dept, Year, Sec) VALUES (" + "'2016-2020','" + PhoneNum + "','VEC','" + Address + "','" + StuID + "','" +DOB +"','1000','" + Name + "','" + Pass + "','" + dept + "','" + year + "','" +sec + "')"             and I get the substituted sql5 as     INSERT INTO MemberDetails ( Validity, PhoneNUM, College, Address, MemberID, DOB, Credits, MEMame, Password, Dept, Year, Sec) VALUES ('2016-2020','g','VEC','g g','g','g','1000','g','g','CSE','First','A')

Comment: I asked you to show what it looks like after all the concatenations are done. Use `print(sql5)` to see it. And put it in the question, not a comment, so you can format it readably.

Comment: I don't see `I` anywhere in that. Is that really what the error message says the error is near?

Comment: Yes I have done the same pls see my comment. Wait, I will comment it again      INSERT INTO MemberDetails ( Validity, PhoneNUM, College, Address, MemberID, DOB, Credits, MEMame, Password, Dept, Year, Sec) VALUES ('2016-2020','g','VEC','g g','g','g','1000','g','g','CSE','First','A')

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. What happens if you try to execute it by hand from the mysql application or PhpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add spacing as well as the columns in the table each variable will be inserted into, your query should be like this:

```
"INSERT INTO MemberDetails (datetime, phone, code, address, stuid, birthdate, num, name, pass, dept, year, sec) VALUES (" + "'2016-2020','" + PhoneNum + "','VEC','" + Address + "','" + StuID + "','" +DOB +"','1000','" + Name + "','" + Pass + "','" + dept + "','" + year + "','" +sec + "')"
```

Just replace the variables in the first set of brackets with the column name you want each variable to be put into.

Comment: You don't need spacing around `+`.

Comment: And you can leave out the list of columns if you're inserting into all the columns of the table in the order that they're defined.

Comment: I know, I was talking about the spacing around VALUES, before it was VALUES( where it should have been VALUES (.

Comment: No, you don't need a space before `(`.

Comment: I just tested it without a space and it worked fine.

Comment: I've always had a syntax error when if I don't have a space before (, now if you've got a better answer for him stop commenting on my answer and provide an actual solution.

Comment: I'm waiting for him to respond to my comment, so I can see what's really wrong with the query.

Comment: I tried that too but its not working see the change :      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MemberDetails VALUES("+"'2016-2020','" + PhoneNum + "','VEC','" + Address + "','" + StuID + "','" +DOB +"','1000','" + Name + "','" + Pass + "','" + dept + "','" + year + "','" +sec + "')")